# I have a string contains ${key} in spring context

Tags: java, spring

I have a simple spring context as following:

```
<bean id="acl.authentication.provider" class="comprovider.ProviderType" factory-method="getInstance">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${key}"/>
</bean>
```

`${key}` isn't a property place holder, it's my real string but spring want fetch it from a property place holder and can't found it so throws a exception.
What can I using `${}` as my real string in spring context?

Comment: why not have that `value` as such, in the `properties` file? `key=${key}`

Comment: I haven't any property file,`${key}` is real and final value.

Comment: I know that. Its just a suggestion to put such an entry in the properties file, because its always a good practice to externalize the static text values, than hardcoding them.

Comment: Oh,suggestion,yes. I do your suggestion but get exception. Spring stil search for `${key}` in property file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have Spring setup here in this machine. Else, would have loved to help more. Without trying, can't say anything. Hopefully, others may help you out. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not really sure it works (because I don't have what to test it at hand) but I think you can trick spring el evaluator by doing the following :

```
<bean id="acl.authentication.provider" class="comprovider.ProviderType" factory-method="getInstance">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="#{'$'+'{key}'}"/>
</bean>
```